# Flutter & Introduction Slider : How do we know that it is the first time our user open the open?

Tags: flutter, slider

Flutter & Introduction Slider :
I want to include introduction slider using this `Intro_Slider` Plugin.
How do we determine when is the first time our user uses the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a boolean field as `isFirstTime` and set it to `true` default value. In `initState()` of `Intro_Slider` you can set it to false, that means user visited this page. And you can save it into `LocalStorage`. After that you can check this value and if `isFirstTime` is false then you can pass this page.

Add package in `pubspec.yaml`:

```
   dependencies:   
      shared_preferences: ^0.5.8
```

Import it:

```
   import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
```

Then:

```
  

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    checkIsFirstTime();
  }

  void checkIsFirstTime() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final bool isFirstTime = prefs.getBool('isFirstTime');

    // check is null or true 
    if (isFirstTime == null || isFirstTime) {     
        prefs.setBool('isFirstTime', false);
    }
    else {
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
    }

  }
```

You can read [more](https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-use-local-storage-in-flutter-3169e34f051b).

Comment: The article isn't free anyway

Comment: Also, I tried your method and I got this error. Why is that?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64441434/flutter-shared-preference-intro-slider-shared-preference-produces-exceptio